# Combining function calls and HTML tags in NEXT in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, next.js

Let's say that I have a function called `Foo()` which outputs "Hello world!", and I want to make a function called `Bar()` which takes the output of `Foo()` and bolds it. Desired output:

> **Hello world!**

Things I have tried:

```js
function Bar() {
    return <b>Foo()</b>;
}
```

Output: **Foo()**

```js
function Bar() {
    var f = <b>Foo()</b>;
    return f;
}
```

Output: **Foo()**

```js
function Bar() {
    var f = Foo();
    return <b>f</b>;
}
```

Output: **f**

```js
function Bar() {
    return "<b>" + Foo() + "</b>";
}
```

Output: `<b>[object Object]</b>`

What do I need to do to get **Hello world!** as the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include a string in JSX, you'll have to add it to a curly braces parentheses.
Here is an example:

```
function Bar() {
  return <b>{ Foo() }</b>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it, though it's not obvious to someone coming from C# and C++.

You need to surround all code declared between HTML tags with curly braces, like this:

```js
function Bar() {
    return <b>{Foo()}</b>;
}
```

The code `{Foo()}` will run the function `Foo` and get its output. You can also put variables here, such as having `var myfoo = Foo();` on the line above, then `{myfoo}` will resolve to the same output.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a  element using the DOM api and set its .innerText property to the value returned by the Foo() function:

```js
function Bar() {
  const boldElem = document.createElement("B");
  return boldElem.innerText = Foo()
}
```